# Replace second to last "/" character in URL with a '#'

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have this URL:

```
http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres/architecture/
```

I would like to replace the second to last `/` with `#` (I need the last `/`) and get the following output:

```
http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres#architecture/
```

I've tried a lot of things with `indexOf()`, `lastIndexOf()` and `substr()`, but I can't get the result I want. I couldn't get any regex solution to work properly, either.

Note that sometimes the link looks like this, with a `-`, too:

```
http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres/art-contemporain/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
var s ='http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres/architecture/';
var r = s.replace(/\/(?=[^/]*\/[^/]*$)/, '#');
//=> http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres#architecture/
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Open your browser console and paste the code as it is. Or use [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), [JSBin](http://jsbin.com), [js.do](http://js.do), [CodePen](http://codepen.io),  or a similar site.

Comment: Just pressing `ctrl-shift-C` brings up Firebug or developer tool console where one can test any Javascript code live.

Answer (score 4):

Below regex will  capture `/` which was just before to the last `/` symbol.

```
.*(\/).*?\/$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/qV9sP4)

Your javascript code would be,

```
var s ='http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres/architecture/';
var r = s.replace(/(.*)(\/)(.*?\/$)/, "$1#$3");
//=>http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres#architecture/
```

Comment: +1 Yep, nicely done and well-presented. :) Fixed a small typo.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var output = input.replace(/\/([^\/]+\/[^\/]*)$/, "#$1" )

/*
input => "http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres/architecture/"
output => "http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres#architecture/" 
*/
```

Comment: // for single line and /* */ for multi line comments :)

Comment: yup, thought it was only for css

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this: `/(\/)([\w-]+\/$)/`

```
    "http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres/architecture/"
     .replace(/(\/)(\w+\/$)/,"#$2"); 
//outputs "http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres#architecture/"
```

Comment: Won't work if input is `http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres/archi-tecture/`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var str = "http://localhost:8888/alain-pers/fr/oeuvres/architecture/";
str = str.replace(/\/(\w+)(\/)?$/,"#$1$2");
```