# Get the string between the last 2 / in regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I get the strings between last 2 slashes in regex in javascript?
for example:

```
stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.html => "ask"
http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar => "regexr.com"
https://www.w3schools.com/icons/default.asp => "icons"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/\/([^/]+)\/[^/]*$/`; `[^/]*$` matches everything after the last slash, `\/([^/]+)\/` matches the last two slashes, then you can capture what is in between and extract it:

```js
var samples = ["stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.html",
               "http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar",
               "https://www.w3schools.com/icons/default.asp"]

console.log(
  samples.map(s => s.match(/\/([^/]+)\/[^/]*$/)[1])
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by using `split()`.

```
let a = 'stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.html';
let b = 'http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar';
let c = 'https://www.w3schools.com/icons/default.asp';

a = a.split('/')
b = b.split('/')
c = c.split('/')
```

indexing after split()

```
console.log(a[a.length-2])
console.log(b[b.length-2])
console.log(c[c.length-2])
```

I personally do not recommend using regex. Because it is hard to maintain

Answer (score 1):

I believe that will do:

`[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]*$)`

`[^\/]+` This matches all chars other than `/`. Putting this `(?=\/[^\/]*$)` in the sequence looks for the pattern that comes before the last `/`.

```js
var urls = [
  "stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/index.html",
  "http://regexr.com/foo.html?q=bar",
  "https://www.w3schools.com/icons/default.asp"
  ];

urls.forEach(url => console.log(url.match(/[^\/]+(?=\/[^\/]*$)/)[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?=[^/]*\/[^/]*$)(.*?)(?=\/[^/]*$)`. You can test it here: https://www.regexpal.com/

The format of the regex is: (positive lookahead for second last slash)(.*?)(positive lookahead for last slash).

The `(.*?)` is a lazy match for what's between the slashes.

references:

1. [Replace second to last "/" character in URL with a '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352076/replace-second-to-last-character-in-url-with-a)
2. [RegEx that will match the last occurrence of dot in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134004/regex-that-will-match-the-last-occurrence-of-dot-in-a-string/11134049#11134049)